# Setting all the UITextfields within the UITableViewCells to editable when edit button is clicked

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

I have embedded textfields in cells and I have an edit button that is supposed to trigger a cell into an edit mode where I can edit the text in the cell.

What I need to do is loop through all the textfields and set the `userInteractionEnabled`to yes. I have done this here in the `setEditing:animated method:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{

[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

if (editing)
{
    int tagNumber = 0;
    for (id cellTextField in [tableView visibleCells]) {
        UITextField *aField = (UITextField *)[cellTextField viewWithTag:tagNumber];
        aField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        tagNumber++;
    }

    self.editButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Done", @"Done");
}
else
{
    self.editButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Delete", @"Delete");
}
}
```

Then I need to somehow put all of those textFields back into the tableview cells. Hope someone can help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised I was being a bit stupid when I forgot the whole point of pointers.

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I added the UITextFields to an array (after adding them as subviews to the cells). Then in the edit button method, I just used fast enumeration to cycle through the array of textFields and changed the userInteractionEnabled property from there.

Here is the code for creating the textfields:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *indexPath
{
  // Configure the cell...
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

  if (cell == nil)
  {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
  }

  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
  tf = nil;

  if (self.currentLevel == 0)
  {
        // create textfield
        tf = [self makeTextField:@"Some text"];          

        // add to subview
        [cell.contentView addSubview:tf];


        // Textfield dimensions
        tf.frame = CGRectMake(20, 12, 170, 30);

        //handle textFieldDidEndEditing
        tf.delegate = self;

        tf.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        [textFieldArray addObject:tf];
  }

 }
```

Here is the code for making them editable:

```
//Edit Button
-(void) editObject:(id)sender
{

  if (editButton.title == @"Edit")
  {
    edit = TRUE;

    // make all textFields editable on click
    for (UITextField *textF in textFieldArray)
    {
        textF.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }        
    editButton.title = @"Done";
  }
  else
  {
    edit = FALSE;

    // make all textFields non-editable on click
    for (UITextField *textF in textFieldArray)
    {
        textF.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
    editButton.title = @"Edit";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code in the UITableView's delegate method, just like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CircleViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UITextField *aField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:tagNumber];
    aField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return cell;
}
```

After this you should handle the edit and done in the edit button's method. BTW, it's better to use a view(subclass of UIView) with XIB file for the UITableViewCell.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sunkehappy. Yes this is the way I have approached it, by adding in tags for the textfields, however it's in the edit button method, where I'm struggling. I can extract the textFields out into an array, but I need to make the textfield's userinteraction enabled directly from that method.